# Is it possible to have the root domain on one web hosting and a sub-domain on another?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, dns-hosting, cloudflare, shared-hosting

I have a shared web-hosting with `CompanyA` and another shared hosting with `CompanyB`. I own one domain called `example.com`. I want to host `example.com` on `CompanyA` and `sub.example.com` on `CompanyB`. Is this possible? I am using cloudflare as my DNS.

If it is possible, how can I do this on cloudflare? A little confused as I have shared hosting and not a VPS

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You would set the A record in DNS for example.com to resolve to the IP address of company A, and create another A record for sub.example.com with the IP address for company B.

Comment: I tried this and when I visit `sub.example.com` it says SSL handshake failed

Comment: @Paul then perhaps sub.example.com does not have a correct ssl certificate for sub.example.com?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Making SSL flexible in cloudflare fixed it

Comment: Please do not forget to accept the answer if it helped you.